# How to read in a file line by line with known format in C

Tags: c, file, input, io, output

The format of the file is as follows

```
month day hour:min:sec process: message
```

Example:

```
Aug 13 12:20:34 automount[1478]: add_host_addrs: hostname lookup failed
```

I am trying to read line by line and for each line read, determine if 'message' contains the word "fail".

I'm getting no output when I run it, please let me know where I am going wrong, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INPUT_SIZE 80

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("logfile", "r");

    char month;
    int day, hour, min, sec;
    char process[INPUT_SIZE];
    char message[INPUT_SIZE];
    char line[INPUT_SIZE];


    if (fgets(line, INPUT_SIZE, file) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
    }
    else
    {
        sscanf("%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %s", &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec, &process, &message);
        printf("%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %s\n", month, day, hour, min, sec, process, message);

        while (strstr(message, "fail"))
        {
            /* do something */
        }
    }


    fclose(file);
    if(line == NULL)
    {
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `char month;` --> `char month[4];` 2) `sscanf("%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %s"...` --> `sscanf(line, "%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %s"...`

Comment: your call to `sscanf` is totally wrong - first argument is your input string then comes the format

Comment: `if(line == NULL)
    {
        free(line);
    }
` shall be deleted. Only `free` things created dynamic, e.g. using `malloc` BTW: `line` can never become NULL

Comment: 3) `%s", &month` --> `%[^\n]", month`

Comment: Why on earth do you emit an error message about opening the file when fgets fails?  If `fopen` fails, call `perror("logfile")`.  If fgets fails, also call `perror("logfile")` and expect an error message that has  nothing to do with opening the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `sscanf()` isn't correct.

Use

```
sscanf(line, "%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %[^\n]", month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec, process, message);
```

where `line` is the string from which you are scanning.

instead of

```
sscanf("%3s %2d %2d:%2d:%2d %s %s", &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec, &process, &message);
```

Notice that in order to read in a string (using `%s`), you use a character array and not a single character.
Since `month` must hold multiple characters, it should be a character array.

As the name of an array decays into its base address, you don't need the `&` operator while providing the address of the strings.
ie, `...%s %s", month, ...process, message)`.

The `message` part of the input string consists of multiple words. Normally `fscanf()` would stop reading after the first space or newline. To keep scanning till newline you could use the `%[^\n]`. It will read till a newline is encountered. This way `message` will have the entire `hostname lookup failed` instead of just `hostname`.

Now that `message` has the complete message, `strstr(message, "fail")` will return non-`NULL` and the control will enter the `while` loop.

`line` was allocated on stack and not on the heap. You shouldn't be doing `free(line)`.

And the size of the buffer `line` will be greater than the other strings which are supposed to hold parts of the data read into `line` with `fgets()`. So using the same size for all strings may not be necessary.

Edit: You can use the `printf()` for output like

```
printf("%s %02d %02d:%02d:%02d %s %s\n", month, day, hour, min, sec, process, message);
```

The `%02d` means add zeros before the number if there are less than 2 digits in it to make the total number of digits 2.

As [Artemy Vysotsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8491726/artemy-vysotsky) commented, the return value of `sscanf()` may be checked to find if all the assignments were successful. `sscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments (or `EOF` on input failure). In this case it must be `7`. If not some error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can fix the output to be "00" format?

For example the output is looking like: "Aug 26  3:47: 1" when it should be "Aug 26 03:47:01"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should check return value of sscanf before using values

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky The last 2 strings are of unknown length. How should the return value be checked?

Comment: @J...S what type of the parameter has to do with return value? `Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf In case of success 7 should be returned. Length of the array provided for %s or %[] has to be used to provide valid format - in OPs case it should be %79s

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Oh! I thought for strings it would return the number of characters. Sorry. Thanks for enlightening!

Comment: @J...S you confuse scanf and printf

Answer (score 0):

Imagine I'm reading the first line of a ".csv" file which contains the data you're looking for, just do this. If it's not the first line, I guess you could manage to parse the rest of the file until you get the word "fail" or any other word you want.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int len = sending();
  char *firstline;
  int i = 0;
  char buf[0];
  int rd ;
  int fd = open("test.csv", O_RDONLY);

  rd = read(fd, buf, 1);    
  firstline = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
  while (i != len)
    {
      firstline[i] = buf[0];
      i++;
      rd = read(fd, buf, 1);
    }
  firstline[i] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", firstline);
  int contains = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (firstline[i]) //loop that verifies if it contains the word "fail"
  {
     if (firstline[i] == 'f' && firstline[i + 1] == 'a' && firstline[i + 2] == 'i' && firstline[i + 3] == 'l')
      ++contains;
     i++;
  }
  return (0);
}

int sending()
{
  int fd = open("test.csv", O_RDONLY);
  char buf[1];
  int r = 0;
  r = read(fd, buf, 1);
  int len = 0;

  while (buf[0] != '\n')//reading until '\n' and getting size to malloc
    {
      len++;
      r = read(fd, buf, 1);    
    }
  return len;
}
```